# How to free the memory correctly in this case

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, pointers, valgrind

How to free the memory correctly in this case ?

I don't understand why does VALGRIND writes that I have:

"Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) "

This is main function:

```
int n=0;
cin >> n;
float* matrix;

matrix = new float [ n * 3 ];

for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
    for( int j = 0; j < 3; j++ ) {
         cin >> *(matrix + i * 3 + j);
    }
}

int* array_of_numbers_of_circles = findIntersection(matrix,n);

for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
    for( int j = 0; j < 2; j++ ) {
        if( *(array_of_numbers_of_circles + i * 2 + j) != 0 ) { //it writes error in if;
            cout << *(array_of_numbers_of_circles + i * 2 + j) << " ";
        }
    }
    if( *(array_of_numbers_of_circles + i * 2 + 0) != 0 && 

    *(array_of_numbers_of_circles + i * 2 + 1) != 0) { //it writes error in if here too;
         cout << "\n";
    }
}

delete[] matrix;
delete[] array_of_numbers_of_circles;
```

and function:

```
int* findIntersection(float matrix[], int n) {
//some variables

int* array_of_numbers_of_circles;

array_of_numbers_of_circles = new int [ n * 2 ];

for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
    for( int j = i + 1; j < n; j++ ) {
        //some code here


        *(array_of_numbers_of_circles + i * 2 + 0) = i + 1;
        *(array_of_numbers_of_circles + i * 2 + 1) = j + 1;

    }
}

return array_of_numbers_of_circles;

}
```

what's the problem? I don't understand why does VALGRIND say such errors

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use std::vector to delete memory automatically and check for buffer overruns.

Comment: Are you sure, the "some code here" does not contain some `continue` or `break` statements? My point is - is it 100% sure, that _all_ elements of `array_of_numbers_of_circles` are _really_initialized? You can also check this with a debugger.

Comment: Why do you use `*(matrix + i * 3 + j)` instead of more common and simple `matrix[i * 3 + j]`?

Comment: You don't initialize all elements of `array_of_numbers_of_circles`. When `i == n-1` in the outer loop, the inner loop executes 0 times. Hence elements at indexes `2 * n - 2` and `2 * n - 1` are not initialized. However, they are used back in `main`, in the line `if( *(array_of_numbers_of_circles + i * 2 + j) != 0 ) `

Comment: @KirilKirov "some code here" (there is the code where I just check smth. and if it is: I do *(array_of_numbers_of_circles + i * 2 + 0) = i + 1;
        *(array_of_numbers_of_circles + i * 2 + 1) = j + 1;

Comment: @KonstantinRasskazov - see Steve's comment. It's a nice catch.

Comment: Use a two-dimensional array, not this low-level pointer twiddling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the warning "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)" is nothing to do with whether you free the memory correctly.

You don't initialize all elements of `array_of_numbers_of_circles`.

When `i == n-1` in the outer loop, the inner loop executes 0 times. Hence elements at indexes `2 * n - 2` and `2 * n - 1` are not initialized. However, they are used back in `main`, in the line `if( *(array_of_numbers_of_circles + i * 2 + j) != 0 )`

Depending on what's in `//some code here`, there may be other elements of the array that are not initialized.

Comment: //some code here means only the rows of code where I check smth and if it is right I do this *(array_of_numbers_of_circles + i * 2 + 0) = i + 1;
        *(array_of_numbers_of_circles + i * 2 + 1) = j + 1;

Answer (score 1):

As the error message kind of suggests, this is probably happening because Valgrind believes you are using values in some way before initializing them. Try using the Valgrind flags to tell you where the source of the uninitialized values are.

In answer to your original question *"How to free the memory correctly in this case ?"*, I would strongly suggest you switch to using `std::vector` and `std::auto_ptr` to make your code more reliable and robust.

Comment: +1. I don't understand why people insist on tossing pointers around, C style, without a compelling need to do so.